# Common/natural ways we might use the continuous and perfect continuous for the verb "to be" ("will be being", "will have been being")?

Tags: tenses, continuous-aspect, aspect, perfect-continuous

I was trying to construct example sentences of the verb "to be" in the usual 12 tenses (or tense-aspects).

First we have these sentences (no problem here):

**Simple**

1. Present: *He is a teacher.*
2. Past: *He was a teacher.*
3. Future: *He will be a teacher.*

**Perfect**

4. Present: *He has been a teacher.*
5. Past: *He had been a teacher.*
6. Future: *He will have been a teacher.*

---

Next, we seem to get some weird sentences (or perhaps my constructions are mistaken--if so, please just let me know):

**Continuous**

7. Present: *He is being a teacher.*
8. Past: *He was being a teacher.*
9. Future: *He will be being a teacher.*

Sentences 7–9 are a bit uncommon/weird, but I guess it's not a stretch to use them in e.g. this context:

John is a teacher.

> Note that when John tries/tried to show you how to do things, he isn't/wasn't being arrogant. He is/was (just) being a teacher.

> Note that when in future John tries to show you how to do things, he won't be being arrogant. He will (just) be being a teacher.

**Perfect Continuous**

10. Present: *He has been being a teacher.*
11. Past: *He had been being a teacher.*
12. Future: *He will have been being a teacher.*

Here I struggle much more to come up with when we'd ever use 10–12. I guess for 12, I could try to adapt the above examples:

> Note that in future, John will try to show you how to do things. He won't have been being arrogant. He will (just) have been being a teacher.

But this sounds really strange and awkward.

**Question.** Are there somewhat common/natural ways we might ever use 10–12?

(Similarly for 7–9: Are there maybe better/more common/natural examples than those I tried to give above?)

Comment: A verb doesn't _have_ to have a use in every conceivable tense! I can't imagine that 10-12 would ever be used in real life.

Comment: @KateBunting: Sure, that could well be the answer, but I was just wondering. Maybe someone here can come up with some surprising examples. Or maybe come up with a nice explanation of why no good natural examples are possible.

Comment: Mother to child's carer: "Is he being good?" Carer: "He's been 'being good' all day." (meaning that he has behaved well.) But this is a 'quirky' use, and in real life most people would say "He's been good all day."

Comment: Your question is far too long. Please remember that we only have a limited amount of time to answer questions.

Comment: "Oh John, stop always trying to be a teacher". "Well, Mathew, he's been being a teacher for ages now and I expect he will be being one for a long time to come". I do not want to write out every usage because I can't be bothered to cite references. bear in mind: being a/the teacher in English can mean: acting like something. John: Well, by the time we tell him to stop forever, he'll have been being the teacher for too long.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you for that.  Is it fair to say that this is a special usage of the verb to be, where 'to be' means 'to behave' in certain ways?  "You are being a nuisance/generous/Napoleon" (the latter applying to an actor, perhaps).

Comment: It think usages 10-12 would suggest to me someone not a native speaker of English ... these would be translations from their own language.

Comment: @GEdgar It depends on context. Resistance is futile (Star Trek). "Stop being so close minded. By the time those guys stop him, he'll have been being a criminal for years".

Comment: It's explained well in LPH's answer. _To be [something]_ in the sense of a temporary state _ 'being annoying' - or acting like a particular type of person - 'being Robin Hood'.

Comment: I doubt you'll get common/natural. Will you settle for weird/forced?

Comment: @greybeard, I rolled your pointless and destructive edit back.

Comment: @TonyK Please note BillJ's comment - **Your question is far too long.** - You are rambling.

Comment: @Greybeard: "we have a limited time to answer questions"? That is unhinged! Nobody is holding a gun to BillJ's head. The question has inconvenienced nobody, except perhaps you and BillJ.

Comment: @TonyK The essence of clear thought is brevity. Could you have written the question better? Were all the examples needed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There exists a natural incompatibility in the use of the progressive in these particular examples. The verb "to be" is par excellence a stative verb, and here is what *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk et al., 1985) has to say about the use of the progressive as concerns those verbs.

> (**CoGEL § 4.26**) **State, event, and habit with the progressive**
>
> The three verb senses of state, event, and habit are differently interpreted
> with the progressive:
> (a) STATE PROGRESSIVE
> In many cases […] the progressive is unacceptable with stative verbs:
>
> - We own a house in the country.
> - *We are owning a house in the country.
> - *Sam's wife was being well-dressed.
>
> This can be explained, in part, by the observation that stative verb meanings
> are inimical to the idea that some phenomenon is 'in progress'. States are
> 'like-parted' in that every segment of a state has the same character as any
> other segment: no progress is made. (Contrast We are building a house in the
> country.) Where the progressive does occur, it is felt to imply temporariness
> rather than permanence:
>
> - We are living in the country. [temporary residence]
> - We live in the country. [permanent residence]
>
> […]

A possibility of such a use of the progressive (with "to be" and other verbs) does exist, but it constitutes a rather marginal usage (not to be undervalued, though).

> (**CoGEL § 4.28**) **Stative types A and B: qualities and states**
>
> Among stative situation types, a rough distinction may be drawn between
> QUALITIES […] and STATES […]. Qualities are relatively permanent and inalienable properties of the subject referent. The primary verbs *be* and *have* are preeminently quality-introducing verbs; but they can also introduce the less permanent situation types called states.
> Contrast:
>
> QUALITIES
>
> - Mary is Canadian. [1]
> - Mary has blue eyes. [2]
>
> STATES
>
> - Mary is tired.[3]
> - Mary has a bad cold. [4]
>
> Normally such stative situation types do not occur with the progressive (this
> is especially trde of qualities):
>
> - *Mary is being a Canadian.[1a]
> - *Mary is having blue eyes. [2a]
> - ?*Mary is being tired. [3a]
> - ?Mary is having a bad cold. [4a]
>
> If sentences such as [1a-4a] do occur with the progressive, it is a sign that they have been in some sense reinterpreted as containing a dynamic
> predication. For example, *Peter is being awkward* signifies that 'awkwardness' is a form of behaviour or activity, not a permanent trait. If sentence [3a] were to occur, it would signify that Mary was *pretending* to be tired (ie indulging in a deceptive activity), rather than in a state of real lassitude.
> Although verbs with stative meaning have sometimes been called
> 'nonprogressive', we should observe that the definition of stative verbs is not so much that they are incompatible with the progressive, as that when they
> are combined with the progressive, some change of interpretation other than
> the addition of the 'temporary' meaning of the progressive aspect is required.
> This change of interpretation can usually be explained as a transfer, or
> reclassification of the verb as dynamic, eg as having a meaning of process or
> agentivity. The representative stative verbs *be, hope, and resemble*, are
> illustrated in Table 4.28:
>
> | NORMAL NONPROGRESSIVE | NONNORMAL PROGRESSIVE | SPECIAL EFFECT OF PROGRESSIVE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | The neighbours are friendly. | The neighbours are being friendly. | Suggests that 'friendliness' is a form of behaviour (perhaps insincere). |
> | I hope you will come. | I am hoping you will come. | Makes the speaker's attitude more tentative and perhaps more polite. |
> | Tina resembles her sister. | Tina is resembling her sister more and more. | With the comparative construction, the progressive turns the stative meaning into a process meaning. |

Note:    *    unacceptable
             ?*    tending to acceptability
              ?    native speakers unsure about acceptability

It follows that the use of "7", "8", and "9" is not normally possible; in the case of qualities, I am not aware that a reinterpretation should be possible. However, I am aware of the recent success of  the expression "[was being a smartass](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+being+a+smartass%2Cis+being+a+smartass&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)" (note that "is being a smartass" is not used), and so there is perhaps a tendancy towards acceptability.

***Addition*** *Here is an excerpt from [Jespersen's grammar](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/A_Modern_English_Grammar_on_Historical_P/olBgow5aJhAC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22been+being+a%22&pg=PT169&printsec=frontcover) that would not have been deemed a superficial complement as a quote in CoGEL (but, of course, the size of books is a limiting factor); this après coup reference is the result of some research prompted by some critical comments, and I would gladly have used it initially if I had been aware of it (I have unfortunately never had the leisure to read Jespersen's grammar, by the way). (user LPH's bold type)*

> Jespersen, Modern English Grammar.
>
> Examples: Keats 5.72 You will be glad to hear … how diligent I have been, and am being | Di D 488 they are always being hungry and discontented somewhere | Benson D 89 Dodo was making an effort to read, but she was not being very successful| Galsw D 193 I am sorry if you think I am being ungrateful | I'm being absurd, I know | Bennet A 205 Now, Mr. Price, the coroner said blandly, and it was plain that he was being ceremoniously polite | NP ' 08 It is very painful to be thought obstinate when one is merely being firm | Russell Soc Reconstr 114 In acting as they do they imagine that they are being virtuous.
> **14.7(4)** **The predicative is generally an adjective denoting some characteristic mental or moral quality, and very often a transitory condition or behaviour is meant in contrast to the person's habitual or real character** (cf. the contrast in Spanish between *soy* and *estoy*, and similar distinctions made in different ways in other languages PG 280). The transitoriness is particularly clear in quotations like these:
> Walpole OL 124 He was only being kind for the moment | id Cp 125 Or was he only being friendly because he was happy? | Wells Br 5 over here we ate being and over there you are beginning | id TB 1. 152 She's been a model—she is a model really [has just been—is professionally] | Shaw A 71 don't be horrid … I'm not being horrid. I'm not going to be horrid.
> **14.7(5)** **Examples with substantives as predicatives are rarer and comparatively unnatural**:
> Benson D 2.309 then I was being a woman, now I am talking as an artist | Lawrence L 191 She was being a heroine in a romance | Wells JP 618 in  certain  matters you are being a fool

Comment: Indeed! for 10, *Johnny has been getting detentions recently because he has been being a smartass".

Comment: Google Books does have some examples of *[he's being a smartass](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22he%27s+being+a+smartass%22&tbm=bks)*, [she's being a smartass](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22she%27s+being+a+smartass%22&tbm=bks),  [I'm being a smartass](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22i%27m+being+a+smartass%22&tbm=bks), [you're being a smartass](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22you%27re+being+a+smartass%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: What are 7, 8 and 9? There don’t seem to be any such example sentences in the answer. And as noted in the comment just above this, the statement that ‘being a smartass’ is only used in the past tense is… very strange, to say the least. It’s perfectly natural in any tense that reasonably fits.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Those three examples were in the OP, which has now been greatly reduced in size.  // The ngram (see the answer) is somewhat wrong: there should probably be in it a near-zero red curve at the bottom; in comparison to the past-continuous, however, the present is hardly used at all, which is what I take as very strange (perhaps those are things that are not said easily when in the presence of the people indulging in this sort of behaviour.)

Comment: I don’t understand that Ngram, to be honest. In actual spoken language, the present-continuous form ‘[someone] is being a smartass’ is at least as common as – probably _more_ common than – the past-continuous form ‘[someone] was being a smartass’. Written texts in general have a natural tendency to skew towards past, since narratives are often written in the past tense, but the complete absence of the present form here is inexplicable to me, especially given the actual examples from Google Books linked to above (which _should_ be included in the Ngram to begin with!).

Comment: You don't start by quoting grammar gurus. The question requires examples not quotations for CGEL: Little Johnny is being a mischevious brat. And he'll probably be being one for a long time to come. OR "John, stop always being a teacher". "Well, Mathew, John's been being **the** teacher around here for ages now and I expect he will be being one for a long time to come". being like that is **acting like**.

Comment: @Lambie "And he'll probably be being one for a long time" doesn't add up to the fact that temporariness and transitoriness should in most cases be characteristics of the action. I will go on believing that such verbal forms are not natural, **and** must be quite rare.

Comment: The two examples given under: "14.7(5) Examples with substantives as predicatives are rarer and comparatively unnatural" are not unnatural *at all*. For example: "then I was being a woman, now I am talking as an artist" He should be ashamed of himself for saying that.  Really bad.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s what [*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) has to say:

> Expressions denoting purely static situations do not combine
> felicitously with progressive aspect: . . .
> <sup>?</sup>*The Earth is being round/flat*; <sup>?</sup>*The solution
> is consisting of salt and vinegar* . . . There are,
> however, several ways in which the progressive can combine with a
> basically stative expression to yield a dynamic interpretation:
>
> [14]  i  *He is being tactful.* [agentive activity]
>         ii  *He’s making more
> and more / fewer and fewer mistakes.* [waxing/waning]
>        iii  *She is cycling to work
> this week.* [temporary state]

Describing agentive activity, *CGEL* continues:

> Non-progressive *He is tactful* is static: we interpret *tactful* as
> denoting a personal quality. Progressive *He is being tactful*
> ([14i]), by contrast, is dynamic: we interpret it as involving
> agentive activity, as describing his present behaviour, “He is
> behaving tactfully”. (There may also be a suggestion that he is
> putting on an act.)

In cases like that, there’s no reason you can’t put the verb through its paces:

> *He’s being stupid. He has been being stupid lately. He will no doubt be being stupid tomorrow.  I’m just being polite. I have been being polite my whole life. He’s just being a good teacher when he tells you to do your homework. By the time he retires, he will have been being a good teacher for forty years.*

Note also that *be being* naturally shows up in the passive voice:

> Active: *They have been harassing him.* Passive: *He has been being
> harassed.* Active: *We will be testing the fire alarm tomorrow.* Passive: *The fire alarm will be being tested tomorrow.*

Comment: But do note that, while finite (_is/are/was/were_) + _being_ is perfectly natural and common in these situations, infinite forms (_be/been/being_) + _being_ does have more bias against it and is more likely to be avoided. “He’s being stupid” and “I’m just being polite” are undeniably commonplace; “He has been being stupid lately” much less so. In natural speech, I’d say most people would find it clunky and would naturally use “He’s been acting stupid lately” instead. In the passive, removing the participle or substituting _getting_ would be more natural as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet People just speak, so to say "best avoided" is just not on.

Comment: @Lambie Neither I nor the answer said that.

Comment: You did say this:  [...] infinite forms (be/been/being) + being does have more bias against it and is more likely to be avoided". Avoided by whom?

Comment: @Lambie Avoided by speakers when speaking naturally. And no, I did not say “best avoided”, which is a prescriptive value judgment – that was exclusively your phrasing. What I said, and stand by, is that speakers are less likely to use the infinite forms than the finite forms in natural speech.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You don't have to repeat it twice. Do you? And I disagree with you anyway. You said: ** is more likely to be avoided**. It depends. If I say: They are really being obnoxious, and have been being that way now for ages. That is completely natural.

Comment: @Lambie Well, it’s not completely natural to me, and it’s rare that I hear it. It’s not ungrammatical, but it’s definitely clunky. In normal conversation, I would just say, “They’re being really obnoxious and have been [that way] for ages now”, dropping out ‘being’ in the compound form, which is exactly what I meant by ‘more likely to be avoided’.